# Generating HTML5 Applications

Tags: javascript, html, templates

When you are using .NET winforms for example, it is possible to generate a form or any other class on the fly. You can create classes in runtime via IL coding, or by letting compiler to generate code and load it into AppDomain and instantiate it and show it via ontheflyform.Show();

I know there are some templating libraries like JQuery Template, Kendo UI templates, Jade is more like what i search i guess but without on the fly generation.

Is there any feasible way to generate HTML5 aplications on the fly?
with requirements like

- routing functionality, like http://domain.tld/customers/edit/1 or http://domain.tld/customers/view/1
- form and dialog creation in runtime via Javascript which would be created by "the thing" i am searching
- possibly with Kendo UI (any better idea) and without any more external dependencies

OR should i write it by myself? what would you do?

What i imagine is like a "some base HTML5 application" which pulls necessary details (forms, links, menu structures,css etc) from server to render what it gets. And no, i dont mean browsers with that but some base HTML5 applications which runs on broswers and renders what it needs to render.

Comment: Depends what you need more, speed of building or flexibility. If you need flexibility, go with individual apps. If you need speed of building, go with a framework.

Comment: Is there any framework for that? speed is way mor important.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any real framework for html5 applications. Your best bet would be to look into development applications for firefox OS, or adobe air.

Comment: I don't know if this goes into your desired direction, but please take a look at Wt which is a C++ web framework that generates all the frontend output automatically, you only deal with objects: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Comment: Thanks Robert, Thanks Michael